# How to change query response array value using MongoDB and PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB. I have created query in mongoDB using php. Using query as follows

```
$date_start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2016-06-08T18:30:00.000Z"));
$default_date = new MongoDate(strtotime("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"));
$pipeline = array(    
array('$project' => array(
        'MainsPower' => 1,
        'EventTS' => 1
        )
),
 array('$unwind' => array(
    'path' => '$MainsPower',
    'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
        )
),
array('$match' => array(
            '$and' => array(
                //array('EventTS' => array('$gt' => $date_start)),
                //array('PanelID' => 'A00911'),
                array("MainsPower" => array('$ne' => null))
            )
        )
),
array(
        '$project' => array(
            'MainsPower' => 1,
            '_id' => 0,
            'EventTS' => array(
                '$add' => array(
                    array('$subtract' => array('$EventTS', $default_date)),
                    array('$multiply' => array( 60000, '$arrayIndex' )) 
                )
            )
        )
),
);
$result = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Query output as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EventTS] => 1497033900000
            [MainsPower] => 204
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EventTS] => 1497034800000
            [MainsPower] => 204
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [EventTS] => 1497035700000
            [MainsPower] => 204
        )
)
```

But, I want my output like this

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EventTS] => [1497033900000, 204]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EventTS] => [1497034800000, 204]
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [EventTS] => [1497035700000, 204]
        )
)
```

Is it possible to change into above format. If is it possible please give me solution.

After post answer converted into PHP

```
$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$unwind' => array(
            'path' => '$MainsPower',
            'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
        )
    ),
    array('$match' => 
            array("MainsPower" => array('$ne' => null))
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'MainsPower' => 1,
            'EventTS' => array(
                '$add' => array(
                     array('$subtract' => array('$EventTS', $var)),
                     array('$multiply' => array( 60000, '$arrayIndex' )) 
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'MainsPower' => array('$literal' => '$MainsPower'),
            'EventTS' => array('$literal' => '$EventTS')
        )
    ),
    array(
        '_id' => 0,
        'EventTS' => array(
            '$concatArrays' => ['$EventTS', '$MainsPower']
        )
    )
);

$result = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Comment: I tried to use $concat inside $project but getting error "$concat only supports strings, not Date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of the **[`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal)** operator (which allows you to return a value without parsing thus you can create a single element array) and the **[`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/#exp._S_concatArrays)** operator to concatenate arrays from different fields into one array. Bear in mind that the **[`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/#exp._S_concatArrays)** operator is only available for MongoDB version `3.2.X` or newer. For earlier versions, use the **[`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/)** operator instead of the **[`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/#exp._S_concatArrays)** as it does the same job.

The following mongo shell aggregation script shows how you can get the desired output using the above operators in the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline:

```
var date_start = new Date("2016-06-08T18:30:00.000Z"),
    default_date = new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    pipeline = [    
        {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$MainsPower",
                "includeArrayIndex": "arrayIndex",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": { "MainsPower": { "$ne": null } }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "MainsPower": 1,                
                "EventTS": {                            
                    "$add": [
                        { "$subtract": ["$EventTS", default_date] },
                        { "$multiply": [60000, "$arrayIndex"] } 
                    ]               
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "MainsPower": { "$literal": ["$MainsPower"] },              
                "EventTS": { "$literal": ["$EventTS"] }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,                           
                "EventTS": {
                    "$concatArrays": ["$EventTS", "$MainsPower"]
                }
            }
        }
    ];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Converting the above to PHP is trivial exercise.

Comment: I tried your code but getting error "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field", I converted in to php and also updated into question can you check correct or incorrect...

Comment: i tried with separating the pipelines but still same issue "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field." and converted in to php updated in to question.
Why showing this kind of error?

Comment: I don't know, there must be an invalid parameter in the pipeline and I'm strongly suspecting the `"$arrayIndex"` field in the first `$project` pipeline. To help you with debugging a troublesome aggregation pipeline, run the aggregation with just the first pipeline operator. If that gives the expected result, add the next. In the example above, you would first try aggregating with just the `$unwind` pipeline; if that works, add the `$match` and so forth.

Comment: thank you much bcoz you solve this.. again thank u so much